# How can I find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ if $\Gamma$ and $\Omega $ are parametrized surface?

Tags: geometry

Let consider two surfaces $$\Gamma=\{\gamma (u,v)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}$$
and $$\Omega =\{\omega (u,v)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}.$$

How can I find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ if $\Gamma$ and $\Omega $ are parametrized surface ? Do I have to pass by cartesian coordinates or I can do it directly ? Let take an example $$\Gamma=\{\gamma (u,v)=(\cos u\sin v,\sin u \sin v, \cos v)\mid v\in [0,\pi], u\in [0,2\pi]\}$$
and $$\Omega =\{\omega (u,v)=(u,v,0)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}.$$

Let $(x,y,z)\in \Gamma\cap \Omega $. The only thing I can say is that there are $u,v\in[0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]$ and $s,t\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $$(x,y,z)=\gamma (u,v)=\omega (s,t),$$
but it won't allow me to the circle $$\theta \longmapsto (\cos \theta ,\sin \theta ,0),\quad \theta \in [0,2\pi].$$
What I did is that I find the cartesian equation of $\Gamma$ and $\Omega $ and then parametrized it as following
$$\Gamma: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\quad \text{and}\quad \Omega : z=0,$$
and thus we find $$\Gamma\cap \Omega :\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=1\\ z=0\end{cases},$$
and thus, after parametrization one finds $$\Gamma\cap \Omega =\{c(\theta )=(\cos\theta ,\sin\theta ,0)\mid \theta \in [0,2\pi]\}.$$

**Question : First of all, I know that my method using cartesian coordinate is correct, and my question is not to know if the way I solved the problem is correct or not since I know it's correct. My question is : Is there a direct method from 
$$\Gamma=\{\gamma (u,v)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}\quad \text{and}\quad \Omega =\{\omega (u,v)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\},$$
to find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ (i.e. *Without Using Cartesian Coordinate*) or I must use them ?**

I would thing about something as : finding $u,v$ s.t. $\gamma (u,v)=\omega (u,v)$ but this doesn't work. Other idea would be to fine $u,v,s,t$ s.t. $\gamma (u,v)=\omega (s,t)$, but still doesn't work, so **How can I do it if it's possible** ?

**So I recall the question : How would you find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ without using coordinate coordinate ?**

Comment: Your example is a good example so that you can quickly find a direct solution, but what about 'bad'  examples?

Comment: @J.Yu: thank you for the answer. What do you mean ? Example where I can't find cartesian coordinates ? May be you can give an example ? The thing is you don't really answer to my question : Is there a possible direct method ? (i.e. not using cartesian equation)

Comment: What do you mean by finding the solution? A provocative way to ensure the question is to say that $\Gamma\cap \Omega$ is the solution! If you want to find points belonging to the solution, you can use numerical methods for that. CAD systems use that a lot. But for many cases, finding exact solutions won't be possible. Think for example to the solution of a degree $5$ polynomial equation. Even for this, finding exact analytical solution is not always possible.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net : I'm sorry, I didn't wrote "finding a solution", did I ?

Comment: To be precise, what do you mean by find $\Gamma\cap \Omega$?

Comment: yes, for example c1: $x^2+y^2 = z$ and c2: $y = x^2 - z^2$, they have simple form, and they can be parametrized easily, but you will take much more time to take out the parametrized form of their intersection 'Directly'.  If you rotate any one of them, it may be much harder.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: ?? $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ mean the intersection of $\Gamma$ and $\Omega $ ? I really don't understand what is ambiguous in my question...

Comment: @J.Yu: Maybe my question was not clear enough (sorry for that), but it's **How in general I can find $\{\gamma (u,v)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}\cap \{\omega (u,v)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}$ ?** I don't want to parametrized anything... the surfaces $\Omega $ and $\Gamma$ are already parametrized...

Comment: The idea of the other comments is that somehow *YES*, your procedure is correct in terms of obtaining the intersection, and might be thought as *the right one* for many 'good' examples like yours for which you can easily find an analytical solution. But **in general** this is not possible or, in other words again, it depends on your example: complicated systems of equations may be impossible to solve analytically (maybe only solvable numerically).

Comment: @Edu: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to know if my procedure is correct or not. I know it is correct. I just want to know if I can find the intersection $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ without passing by cartesian coordinate. I don't know how to do. For example, if $\Gamma=\{\gamma (u,v)=(\cos u\sin v, \sin u\sin v,\cos v)\mid u\in [0,2\pi], v\in [0,\pi]\}$ and $\Omega =\{\omega (u,v)=(u,v,0)\mid u,v\in \mathbb R\}$, how would you find $\Omega \cap \Gamma$ **without using cartesian coordinates** ?

Comment: Still, it's not entirely clear what you mean by *find the intersection*, given that the intersection is an infinite set so you obviously cannot write out all its elements. One simple way to write the intersection is as the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:\exists u,v,s,t\in\mathbb R\text{ s.t. }\gamma(u,v) = (x,y,z,) = \omega(s,t)\}$, but I suppose that is not what you want. ...

Comment: ... Given the example in your question, I would guess that you want a *parametrized* form $\{c(\theta):\theta\in I\}$ for some function $c:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ and interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$, but that is contradicted by your comment that you "don't want to parametrized anything".

Comment: @Rahul : How would you find $$\{(\cos u\sin v, \sin u\sin v, \cos v)\mid u\in [0,2\pi], v\in [0,\pi]\}\cap\{(u,v,0)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}=\{(\cos\theta ,\sin\theta ,0)\mid \theta \in [0,2\pi]\},$$ without using cartesian coordinate ? Is the question clear enough like this ?

Comment: @Rahul : How would you find $$\{(\cos u\sin v, \sin u\sin v, \cos v)\mid u\in [0,2\pi], v\in [0,\pi]\}\cap\{(u,v,0)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}$$ without using cartesian coordinate ? Is the question clear now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $ where $\Gamma$ and $\Omega $ are parametrize surface.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831265/find-gamma-cap-omega-where-gamma-and-omega-are-parametrize-surface)

Answer (score -2):

Calling $\gamma(u,v)=\Gamma$ and $\omega(u,v)=\Omega$ the two intersecting surfaces we have

$$
p_1 = p_1(u_1,v_1) \leftarrow \gamma(u_1,v_1) = \Gamma\\
p_2 = p_2(u_2,v_2) \leftarrow \omega(u_2,v_2) = \Omega
$$

where $p_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i), \;\; i \in \{1,2\}$

For generic surfaces, the intersection can be obtained by solving by an iterative procedure like Newton-Raphson methods.

So our problem is to solve

$$
p_1(u_1,v_1)-p_2(u_2,v_2) = 0
$$

which gives three equations and four unknowns. The missing equation is used as initial point locator and then as a step constraint.

This problem can also be handled as a minimization problem or as

$$
\min_{u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2}||p_1-p_2||
$$

I hope to be helpful.
Attached the result for the Newton-Raphson iterative process application to the intersection curve determination. The algorithm used is a simpler one without step uniformity correction.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you. Could you please adapt this method to my example ? i.e. to find $\Gamma\cap \Omega $  where $\Gamma=\{\gamma (u,v)=(\cos u\sin v,\sin u\sin v,\cos v)\mid u\in [0,2\pi], v\in [0,\pi] \}$ and $\Omega =\{(u,v,0)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}$. Because I can't conclude using your method.

Comment: I also would be curious how you can conclude with this method (that I'm not sure to understand totally... why $\gamma (u,v)=0$ and $\omega (u,v)=0$ ?).

Comment: @Surb   Oh my! Just a distraction! I am sorry! I am working an example to show the method.

Comment: @MSE I included the result for the suggested process.

Comment: @MSE As I could observe, some guys don't appreciate very much numerical recipes.