# Find $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B$ without using cartesian coordinate.

Tags: geometry

I have $$\mathcal A=\{\gamma (u,v)=(\cos(u)+1,v,\sin(u))\mid u\in [0,2\pi], v\in \mathbb R\}$$
and $$\mathcal B=\{(u,u,v)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}.$$

How can I find $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B$ without using the cartesian coordinate ?

---

I know how to find the intersection using cartesian coordinate, and I found $$\{c(u)=(\cos(u)+1,\cos(u)+1,\sin(u))\mid u\in [0,2\pi]\}.$$

But here I way able to find the cartesian equation of both set, and thus conclude. But in case where I can't find those cartesian equation, how could I proceed ? Typically, how could I proceed here without using cartesian coordinate ?

Comment: why the downvote ? In what this is a bad question ? Please explain.

Comment: As I already asked below [the other identical (but now deleted) question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2831265/415941): how you want your result to be given? As a parametric curve? Then you will need use cartesian coordinates. Why you even want to avoid the coordinates? The whole task seems to be made for coordinates. If you explain a bit more about your motivation, maybe we better understand how to help you. Also please explain the significant difference to [your other similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2831186/415941).

Comment: @M.Winter: Thank you for your comment. The thing it's not that I want to avoid cartesian equation, but I was wondering if it's possible to do without it. Because I agree that I was always able to find the cartesian equation, but in the case where I'm not allowed to find it, I was wondering how to find this intersection.  The result can be in any form (I just want the equation of a curve, and it's easy after to parametrize a curve). Here for example it should be an ellipse... But indeed, the aim is to have the parametrization of the intersection (here, the parametrization of the curve).

Comment: @M.Winter: So for example is there a why to find directly the parametrization of the intersection without using the cartesian equation of each set ?

Comment: The question is more: what do you accept as an answer. If the answer would be a circle, then how would you state this without cartesian coordinates? Both, $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $r(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$ use coordniates. Just writing $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B$ seems not to be an appropriate answer for you. What form of an answer you would accept, if the answer would be a circle. Or if you already know that it is an ellipse, in what non-cartesian form you would accept the answer?

Comment: I would argue that because you want a cartesian answer (a parametrization), the path has to be cartesian as well. One possible other way would be to find five points in $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B$ (by systematical guessing) and from these compute the parametrization of the ellipse (which is uniquely defined by these points). But that seems overly complicated.

Comment: @M.Winter: Thanks again for your comment. I would accept any answer if we don't use the fact that $\mathcal A : (x-1)^2+z^2=1$ and $\mathcal B: x-y=0$. So indeed, if you arrive to the cartesian equation of a circle just by using that $\mathcal A=\{(cos(u)+1,v,\sin(u))\mid u\in[0,2\pi]\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{(u,u,v)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}$ it's fine for me. But I have to admit that I would prefer to arrive to $\{(\cos(t)+1,\cos(t)+1,\sin(t))\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}$ directly from $\mathcal A=\{(cos(u)+1,v,\sin(u))\mid u\in[0,2\pi]\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{(u,u,v)\mid u,v\in\mathbb R\}$ (if it's possible).

Comment: Would *guessing* the answer and showing that it is correct also count? And could it be that you really want to avoid the **implicite representation** of the surfaces, not coordinates in general?

Comment: @M.Winter: You are just making fun of me... that's not nice.

Comment: No! Sorry if this is your impression. I am certainly not making fun of you. It's just really important to completely understand the problem and your inteded solution to help you. Many problems in math can be solved by some "intuition" (which I meant by "guessing"). It usually suffices to show that the solution is correct, then the path is not so important. What I wanted to know is whether the path is important for you, or it suffices to show that the solution is indeed right without using coordinates. Also I was honestly wondering whether you might use the term coordinates wrong. I can't know.

Comment: @M.Winter: Oh, sorry for my bad interpretation :-) So I don't want to "guess" the solution (here we could indeed guess if the intersection is a circle or an ellipse, but I don't think that you can guess which ellipse it is... or me I cannot). The thing I was really wondering if using parametrization we can find intersection points. If you have for example two functions $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto g(x,y)$, to find intersection points of those function consist on finding $x,y$ s.t. $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$.

Comment: @M.Winter:But it looks that for parametrized surface (or even curve), things work differently. For example consider curves over $\mathbb R^2$ as $\gamma (t)=(\gamma _1(t),\gamma _2(t))$ and $\theta (t)=(\theta _1(t),\theta _2(t))$. How would you proceed to find intersections point ? Because just finding $t$ s.t. $\gamma (t)=\theta (t)$ is not enough since they have no reason to be at the same position for the same $t$, i.e. we can have $\gamma (t)=\theta (s)$ for $s\neq t$. But if we can't give a cartesian equation of those two curve, is there a general way to find intersection points ?

Comment: That is true, finding intersections of general curves is (really) hard, theoretically and also numerically. You can formulate it as a 2D optimization problem: find the minimum of $\|\gamma(t)-\theta(s)\|$ over $(s,t)\in\Bbb R^2$. You found an intersection if the optimal value is zero. But there is no shortcut and most theoretical and numerical procedures are dependent on the exact curves you are working with.

Comment: @M.Winter: Thank you for your answer. I guess it's the same with intersections of surfaces in general, no ?

Comment: You are welcome :) I think the technique works for more general parametrized surfaces. But you have to be cautious. There is no quarantee that you have found all intersection curves (two surfaces can intersect in more than one curve), and there is no guarantee that the equations are so easy to manipualte as in the case of your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ is a curve. So what you want to find is the parametrization of a curve that lies in *both* surfaces. So let's look at how we can describe curves in parametrized surfaces.

A curve in $\mathcal A$ is given by functions $u,v:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$:

$$t\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\cos(u(t))+1 \\ v(t) \\ \sin(u(t)) \end{pmatrix}.$$

A curve in $\mathcal B$ is given by function $\bar u,\bar v:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$:

$$t\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\bar u(t)\\\bar u(t)\\\bar v(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

All we have to do is to choose these function $u,v,\bar u,\bar v$ in a clever way, so that these give rise same curve, i.e.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos(u(t))+1 \\ v(t) \\ \sin(u(t)) \end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}\bar u(t)\\\bar u(t)\\\bar v(t)\end{pmatrix}
$$

for all $t\in\Bbb R$. These are three equations for $u,v,\bar u$ and $\bar v$:

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{I.} &&\cos(u(t))+1 &=\bar u(t),\\
\mathrm{II.} &&v(t)&=\bar u(t), \\
\mathrm{III.} &&\sin(u(t)) &= \bar v(t).
\end{align*}

It should be clear that the solution cannot be unique, as there is more than one way to parametrize an curve. So let's fix the $u(t)$ and lets see what the other functions are in terms of $u$.

This is pretty easy:

- Equation I determines $\bar u(t)$.
- Equation III determines $\bar v(t)$.
- Knowing $\bar u(t)$, equation II determines $v(t)$ as well.

We are done. Exemplary choose $u(t)=t$ (the easiest I can think of). Then we obtain

\begin{align}
\bar u(t) &= \cos(t)+1, \\
\bar v(t) &= \sin(t), \\
v(t) &= \cos(t)+1.
\end{align}

And thats it. Substituing these functions into the surface parametrizations gives the same curve $(\cos(t)+1,\cos(t)+1,\sin(t))$ (an ellipse) on both surfaces. You can replace $u(t)$ by other functions to find other parametrizations of the solution, but we already found the "natural one".

Comment: Every thing is perfect (I didn't see you answer in comment below). It's what I wanted to know : "finding intersection point is very hard in general". I wasn't sure if methods exist or not. I also like very much how you solve this exercise. Bravo and thank you very much :-)